# How to decode password in asp.net core 2.0, which is encoded by System.Web.Security.MembershipProvider asp.net 3.5

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-membership

We have existing application which manages login using Membership provider. Now we are creating new application which uses asp.net core 2.0. How can I decrypt the password in .net core which is encrypted by membership provider?

Comment: What you have is likely a hash of the password, which cannot be decrypted to reveal the password. You should use the same hashing algorithm in Core (if possible) and leave the hashes intact.

Comment: No we are not using a hash. it is using System.Web.Security.MembershipProvider  MembershipPasswordFormat.Encrypted  which uses the System.Web.Security.MembershipProvider.DecryptPassword( .. )

Comment: OK sounds good thanks

Comment: @NileshPore, did you find a solution to this? I'm currently fighting the same battle.

Comment: No, we changed existing password mechanism with standard password encryption algorithm. We updated existing passwords with new algorithm.